# Python Scrapy: how to code the parameter instead of using cmd: use Custom code in Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using [Scrapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrapy) 0.20 with Python 2.7.

I used to do this in cmd,

```
 -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
```

to handle the dublicated items. **Note please, I already did the changes in setting**

I dont' want to use that in cmd.

Is there a way I can type it in code inside my spider?

Comment: Edit the topic such that the new one is more relevent..

Answer (score 1):

It's so easy. Use dropitem in pipelines.py to drop the item. And you can use custom command to code the parameter inside of program.

[Here is example of custom code in scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html)

Using the custom command (say : `scrapy crawl mycommand`)

you can run `-s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1`

Example:

Create a directory `commands` where you have `scrapy.cfg` file
Inside the directory create a file `mycommand.py`

```
from scrapy.command import ScrapyCommand
from scrapy.cmdline import execute



class Command(ScrapyCommand):
    requires_project = True

    def short_desc(self):
        return "This is your custom command"


    def run(self, args, opts):
        args.append('scrapy')
        args.append('crawl')
        args.append('spider')##add what ever your syntax needs.In my case i want to get "scrapy crawl spider" in cmd
        execute(args)#send a list as parameter with command as a single element of it
```

Now go to cmd line and type scrapy `mycommand`. Then your magic is ready :-)

Comment: could you clarify more

Comment: i will give you a sample then

Comment: and i will explain you it. just try to figure out how it works. and if you have problem, you can ask again

Comment: I understood that i can do this `self.jobdir = 'something`, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48812/discussion-between-nabin-and-marco-dinatsoli)